# How to Append Unique Rows and Take Its Values and put in a Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

This is my initial df:

```
 Date        Items  Stocks  Sold
 11/07/2020  Item1   10    40
 11/08/2020  Item1   20    50
 11/09/2020  Item1   30    90
 11/10/2020  Item1   30    30
 11/07/2020  Item2   10    10
 11/08/2020  Item2   20    100
 11/09/2020  Item2   30    70
 11/10/2020  Item2   40    80
```

I want to create a new df that is grouped by per item, like so

```
Items  Stocks Sold
Item1  90     210
Item2  100    260
```

Here's my code:

```
item = df.groupby['Items'].unique()
stocks = df.groupby('Items')['Stocks'].sum()
sold = df.groupby('Items')['Sold'].sum()

dff = pd.DataFrame({'Item': item, 'Stocks': stocks, 'Sold': sold})
```

It's working however, the numbers are all mixed up. I'm getting this result:

```
Items  Stocks Sold
Item1  100   260
Item2  90    210
```

How do I make sure that each value has the right number in my df when I groupby.

Comment: `df.groupby('Items', as_index=False).sum()` Or `df.groupby('Items')[['Stocks','Sold']].sum()`

Comment: @QuangHoang how about if I have to get the 'mean()' as well for other columns in the df? How do i add that in the code?

Comment: `df.groupby('Items', as_index=False).agg({'Stocks':'sum', 'Sold': 'mean'})`...

Comment: To get both sum and mean:  `df.groupby('Items', as_index=False).agg({'Stocks':('sum', 'mean'), 'Sold': ('sum', 'mean')})`

Comment: @QuangHoang I'm getting an error that says: 'str' object has no attribute 'agg'

Comment: @SeaBean I'm getting an error that says: 'str' object has no attribute 'agg'

Comment: What's the dtype of your `Stocks` and `Sold` columns ?   I imported your data and run without problem.  The dtypes are both int64 in my converted dataframe.

Comment: @SeaBean the dtypes are int now however, I'm getting a syntax error on as_index=False statement.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df.groupby('Items', as_index=False)[['Stocks', 'Sold']].sum()
```

Output:

```
    Items   Stocks  Sold
0   Item1   90      210
1   Item2   100     260
```

And if you want different agg functions for different columns:

```
df.groupby('Items', as_index=False)[['Stocks', 'Sold']]\
  .agg(stocks_mean=('Stocks', 'mean'), sold_sum=('Sold', 'sum'))
```

Output:

```
    Items   stocks_mean     sold_sum
0   Item1      22.5            210
1   Item2      25.0            260
```

Comment: I'm getting a syntax error on as_index=False statement.

Comment: Your original dataframe that you try to apply this code on it, is the same as this sample dataframe?

Comment: it's the same, I just have more columns in my original df but they're all just numbers, so I'm just also trying to get the sum and mean on other columns

Comment: Try this:
`df.loc[:, [['Stocks', 'Sold']] = df[['Stocks', 'Sold']].astype(float)`  And then apply the above method on them.